# How to change the collision shape for individual instances?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm working on a game where a level is separated into rooms where the camera is confined into the current room, meaning the camera wont "bleed" into adjacent ones. A room is a scene RoomBase consisting of Positions RoomLimitTopLeft and RoomLimitBottomRight (which define the camera's limits) and an Area2D which detects when the player enters the room. As each room's size and exits will wary, I created a script which streches the Area2D's CollisionShape to the rooms's size.

RoomBase.gd

```
const ROOM_TRANS_LIMIT = 16
onready var limit_tl = $RoomLimitTopLeft # Position
onready var limit_br = $RoomLimitBottomRight # Position
onready var room_transition = $RoomTransition # Area2D
onready var room_transition_coll = $RoomTransition/CollisionShape2D

func setRoomTransition():
    var width = limit_br.position.x - limit_tl.position.x - 2*ROOM_TRANS_LIMIT
    var height = limit_br.position.y - limit_tl.position.y - 2*ROOM_TRANS_LIMIT

    self.room_transition.position = Vector2(limit_br.position.x/2, limit_br.position.y/2)
    self.room_transition_coll.shape.set_extents(Vector2(width/2, height/2))
```

This code centers the Area2D's position to its room and stretches its collision to cover almost the whole room, which works fine with only one room. However, if a level consists of multiple rooms, the most recent room instance overwrites the collision shape of the previous ones. For example, if Room 1 is horizontal and Room 2 is vertical, then Room 1 will share 2's vertical collision shape.

Is it possible to change an individual scene instances collisions without affecting any others?

Comment: By the way, you can type your variables. For example `onready var room_transition:Area2d = $RoomTransition`. See [Static typing in GDScript](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/static_typing.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could also change the setting of the node, if possible, in the Inspector[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, the 'Local To Scene' I needed to check was in the shape's Resource tab and not the material's like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the issue, but for what I understand you are using the same [`Shape2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_shape2d.html) for every room. If all they are all using the same `Shape2D`, and you modify that `Shape2D`, the changes are reflected in all of them.

You can [`duplicate`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_resource.html#class-resource-method-duplicate) the `Shape2D` from code (or make it unique from the inspector). That way you have a different `Shape2D`.